# Can Solidity return values in a specific unit so that the Wallet shows them nicely?

Tags: solidity, wallets

I asked this question, and then I figured out the answer with help from folks here in this exchange.

QUESTION

I have contract functions that return a uint256 amount. This amount is related to the contract's balance. So it shows up in Wei (I guess), as a very large number, in Ethereum Wallet.

Can I return this number in Ether so that it shows up in a more friendly way in the Wallet and I don't risk messing up units in calculations? Or do I have to manually convert units and return a uint256 as divided by some constant?

ANSWER

Well, a function returns a value of a given type, for example, in this case, uint256.

The money units available in solidity are constants, and have no relation to the type system.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually convert it once the contract function has returned the value with the web3 object.

For the old web3 object you can do `web3.fromWei(weiValue, 'ether')` where 'weiValue' is the value your contract function returns, to get the value as Ether.

For the new web3 object, version 1.0, it will be `web3.utils.fromWei(weiValue, 'ether')` where 'weiValue' is a string of the value your contract returns. Note you have to convert it to a string first. See: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is a point missing and I would be very thankful if you could help as well: can I configure the Ethereum Wallet to read those values in friendlier way?

Comment: When you say Ethereum Wallet, are you referring to Mist?

Comment: I was using the default ethereum wallet. I don't know if it is mist; but I figured out what was wrong and I will edit the question and turn it into a KB page.